# Why is `CMSG_SPACE` not a constant function in Rust?

Tags: rust, libc, compile-time-constant

According to [the documentation](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.101/libc/fn.CMSG_SPACE.html):

```rust
pub const unsafe extern "C" fn CMSG_SPACE(length: c_uint) -> c_uint
```

However, if I compile

```rust
fn main() {
    let _ = [0u8; libc::CMSG_SPACE(1) as usize];
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0015]: calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
 --> src/bin/libc-const.rs:2:27
  |
2 |     let _ = [0u8; unsafe {libc::CMSG_SPACE(1) as usize}];
  |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0015`.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `const-extern-fn` [feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc) for `libc` [is required](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/blob/5fefaf60adedda5eeb9e5896cc43fb02eb96a6c9/src/macros.rs#L156-L199) to be active for this function to be `const`. The version documented on `docs.rs` has this feature enabled, which is why it is (unfortunately) shown as being `const` by default. This feature requires a nightly rustc.